# Why aren't all Shapefile vector features displayed correctly?

Tags: qgis

I am a new user of QGIS 1.8.0. I do not display correctly SHP layer. When I want zooming layer so that half of the layer is outside the map window - display layer disappears. In the settings I can not find a way to stop this.
SHP layer is visible only when the complete layer fits in the map window.

---

Update:

The problem is solved. Viewing layers functioning incorrectly in layers containing. Qix file. If I leave only at layer shp, dbf and shx everything is fine. Qix I have to delete all the layers are displayed well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange forum.Please upload the screenshot regarding your query..few tutorials links for you. http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/qgis-video-tutorials/, http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/

Answer (score 1):

Need to elaborate i think. Did you create the layer? Check scale dependent rendering in the properties panel under general and then tick it off.

[image]